# How can I change the creation time of all a folder's files to the current time?

Tags: linux, command-line, touch

Under a Linux shell, how can I change the creation time of all a folder's files to the current time?

Comment: The files don't have a 'create time' but they do have a 'modification time'. To change the modification time of a file you use the `touch` command, e.g. `$ touch file1 file2 file3`

Comment: Were these answers helpful to you @tomy?

Comment: @boehj Thanks for pointing out that files don't have a creation time

Answer (score 5):

The OP asked for the **creation** time, but [Ian Yang](https://superuser.com/a/299100/112297) and [boehj](https://superuser.com/a/299069/112297) answers are based on command `touch` setting the **modification**, **access** and **change** times to current time.

As boehj said (in his comment) there is no **creation** time of a file... This is true for most of the filesystems, but on some modern filesystems (as [ext4](https://serverfault.com/questions/351836/whats-birth-field-in-stat-command-output)) the **creation** (or **birth**) time of a file is stored within the [inode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode).

Therefore we can give a more correct answer scrupulously respecting the question title:

```
cp -a  your-folder tmp-folder
rm -rf your-folder
mv tmp-folder your-folder
```

This will change the **creation** time (**birth** time) to the current time. This also updates the **change** time but keep unchanged the **modification** and **access** times.

For information, the **change** time is sometimes abbreviated as `ctime` and can be confused with the **creation** time (`crtime` or `btime`). In fact, the **change** time of a file is the **modification** time of its corresponding [inode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode). Therefore commands modifying `inode` content as `chmod` or `chattr` also set the **change** time to current time.

Comment: As far as I know, most if not all Linux filesystems do not save a creation time.

Comment: Thank you @terdon for your comment, I have updated my answer (change comment is *"creation time available on some modern filesystems only as stated by terdon"*). Cheers ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Navigate to the folder in question, let's say, ~/Documents/myfiles.

```
$ cd ~/Documents/myfiles
```

Then do:

```
$ touch *
```

This will change the modification time to whenever you executed that command.

Obviously you can make this more specific depending on your use case, e.g.

```
$ touch *.doc
```

will only alter the modification time for files with the string '.doc' in their name.

Answer (score 2):

In Linux, if you want to do some thing recursively in directory, or you want to apply some actions on files meeting some criterions，you should try `find` and `xargs`

Touch all files in ~/Documents/myfiles (including files in sub directory)

```
find ~/Documents/myfiles -type f -print0 | xargs -0 touch
```

Comment: Without `xargs`: `find dir -type f -exec touch {} +` (sets to now the modification/access/change times of all files recursively)